# How to add a custom link when sharing post to facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sharer

[image]

Above is an example of a custom link added below the post in facebook. The "play" link src changes when you share it from different page of the third party website.

How to add a custom link using php?
The name of link is it possible to have a different name? 
How many custom link can be added?

// edit: [img link](http://oi59.tinypic.com/2m2ca38.jpg)

Comment: Image doesn’t load for me, but I suppose that what Facebook calls _action links_ might be what you’re after. (And the maximum is one per post.)

Comment: Hi @CBroe i upload the img again.

Comment: Yeah, as I said – “action links”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a custom link to the end of Like and Share by using the `actions` parameter. For example:

```
$post = $facebook->api( "me/feed", "POST", array(
    'message' => 'Testing custom search action',
    'actions' => array(
        'name' => 'Search',
        'link' => 'http://www.google.com'
      )
  ) );

print_r( $post );
```

Will produce:

[image]